# Using ee.Reducer.percentile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon, javascript, google

I tried to reduce the resolution of the land cover map from 100m to 1000m, by putting the condition that if for example, 60 percent of the same value can be found in 1000m, we do the aggregation. For doing that, I used `ee.Reducer.percentile`, which apparently does not do the job!

This is my code:

```js
var dataset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('forest_type')
var forest= dataset.updateMask(dataset.gt(0))
print(forest)

var abundance_perc = (forest.reduceRegion({reducer:ee.Reducer.percentile([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]), geometry:geometry, scale:1000,maxPixels: 100e13
}));
print(abundance_perc)

var top90 = forest.gte(ee.Number(abundance_perc.get("forest_type_p90")))

Map.addLayer(top90)


var top10 = forest.gte(ee.Number(abundance_perc.get("forest_type_p90")))

Map.addLayer(top10)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d038f6e9bc10572187394fc61a6f95b5

Comment: Your code is completely off base. I suggest looking up how percentile works (in general, and as a function) because it was never intended to be a tool for upscaling.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem. I should have written this part:
var top10 = forest.gte(ee.Number(abundance_perc.get("forest_type_p10")))

like this:
var top10 = forest.updateMask(forest.gte(ee.Number(abundance_perc.get("forest_type_p10"))))

In general, do you think my framework is logically correct?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).